# Entity Framework 6 Relationship and Inclusion Issue

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have the following POCOs running on a legacy EF6 API  (reduced for brevity).

```
public class Customer 
{

    [ForeignKey("Parent")]
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
    public Customer Parent { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Site> Sites { get; set; }
}

public class Site 
{
    public List<Department> Departments { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following fluent api configuration on the customer entity;

```
HasOptional(x => x.Sites).WithOptionalDependent().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
```

and on the site entity;

```
HasOptional(r => r.Customer).WithMany().HasForeignKey(r => r.CustomerId);
```

However, when I run the following query form a customer perspective (and look to include the sites)

```
context.Where<Customer>(x => x.ParentId == null,
                    x => x.Sites).ToList();
```

Where the method Where is;

```
    public List<T> Where<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, params Expression<Func<T, object>>[] includes) where T : class, IEntity
    {
        return this.AsQueryable(includes).Where(predicate).ToList();
    }
```

I receive the error message;

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandCompilationException: An error occurred while preparing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.Entity.Core.MetadataException: The declared type of navigation property CCS.Data.UCare.Customer.Sites is not compatible with the result of the specified navigation.

The tables generate by EF in the database are as follows;

[image: Customers Table MSSQL]

[image: Sites Table MSSQL]

Can anyone advise on where I am going wrong here please?

**UPDATE**

I have also tried a fresh rebuild of the database (removed all migrations and run as fresh `add-migration` and `update-database` to a new test database). But the problem still persists.

Comment: Did you forget to post the query?  And normally you don't configure the same relationship  twice.  Perhaps if you include the table DDL it will show something obviously wrong.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Sorry, yes I did. I updated the question to include this now.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft I have added in the MSSQL screenshot to show the relationships build by EF and to me it all looks ok? Any Ideas?

Comment: Why do you have a custom API for filtering entities?  If you simply delete that code and specify the filters and includes in the normal way you should fix this problem, and have less code.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try:

```
HasOptional(r => r.Customer).WithMany(c => c.Sites).HasForeignKey(r => r.CustomerId);
```